# If $A$ is compact then $f^{-1}(A)$ compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

Let $f$ be a continuous function. I know that if $A$ is compact then $f(A)$ is compact but is $f^{-1}(A)$ also compact?
I believe it is not but how can I prove it by a counter example?

Comment: No, consider a non injective function like $f(x)=0$.

Answer (score 6):

Consider $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R $ defined by $f (x)=1$. The set $\{1\} $ is compact, but $f^{-1}(\{1\})=\mathbb R $ is not.